# Toggle between icons depending on number of child elements

Tags: javascript, html

I figured out how to change the icon when more elements are added, but I can't figure out to how return it to the original icon while the cart is empty.

Javascript

```
let cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-container')[0];

if (cartItems.childElementCount <= 1) {
    let cartBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-btn')[0]
    cartBtn.innerHTML = `
    <i class="fa fa-cart-plus cart-btn text-danger"></i>`
}
```

HTML

```
<h1 class="cart-btn">
  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
</h1>

<div class="container cart-container d-flex flex-column pb-5">
  <div class="row mt-5 mb-4">
    <div class="col">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think your question is very clear.

Comment: I posted an answer to my question! Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

I have a shopping cart button on a navbar that I need to switch between different states depending on if the cart is empty or not. I figured out how to change it to one state when an item was added to the cart, but couldn't figure out how to change it back to the original state when I emptied the cart. However, I used this code to accomplish that task.

Javascript

```
function checkNavBtn() {
    let cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-container')[0];
    let cartBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-shopping-cart')[0];
    if (cartItems.childElementCount >= 0) {
        cartBtn.classList.add('fa-cart-plus', 'text-danger');
    } if (cartItems.childElementCount <= 0) {
        cartBtn.classList.remove('fa-cart-plus', 'text-danger');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can just toggle the class instead of replacing entire HTML inside an element :)